# mapstruct type conversion for different field types doesnt works

Tags: java, nested, mapping, mapstruct

In quarkus project I try to map DataSyncConfigurationMapping and DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity with using MapStruct 1.5.5.Final version, except columnNames/columnNameList fields other field types matches and when tested the other field mappings works smoothly. What i have missed, any helps?

```
public class DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String columnNames;
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;
    private DataSyncConfigurationEntity dataSyncConfiguration;
}
```

```
public class DataSyncConfigurationMapping{
    private Long id;
    private List<String> columnNameList;
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;
    private DataSyncConfiguration dataSyncConfiguration;
}
```

```
public class DataSyncConfigurationEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String fileName;
    private String sqlStatement;
    private String columnNames;
    private String cron;
}
```

```
public class DataSyncConfiguration{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String fileName;
    private String sqlStatement;
    private List<String> columnNameList;
    private String cron;
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jakarta", uses = {DataSyncConfigurationMapper.class})
public interface DataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "dataSyncConfiguration.columnNames", target = "dataSyncConfiguration.columnNameList",
            qualifiedByName = "stringToListConverter")
    DataSyncConfigurationMapping entityToPojo(DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity entity);
    @Mapping(source = "dataSyncConfiguration.columnNameList", target = "dataSyncConfiguration.columnNames",
            qualifiedByName = "listToStringConverter")
    DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity pojoToEntity(DataSyncConfigurationMapping pojo);
    @Named("stringToListConverter")
    default List<String> map(String value) {
        return stringToList(value);
    }
    @Named("listToStringConverter")
    default String map(List<String> list) {
        return listToString(list);
    }
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jakarta")
public interface DataSyncConfigurationMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "columnNames", target = "columnNameList")
    DataSyncConfiguration entityToPojo(DataSyncConfigurationEntity entity);
    @Mapping(source = "columnNameList", target = "columnNames")
    DataSyncConfigurationEntity pojoToEntity(DataSyncConfiguration pojo);
    default List<String> map(String value){
        return stringToList(value);
    }
    default String map(List<String> list){
        return listToString(list);
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MapperUtils {
    public static List<String> stringToList(String columnNames) {
        if (columnNames == null) {
            return null;
        }        return Arrays.asList(columnNames.split(","));
    }
    public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return String.join(",", list);
    }
}
```

```
@QuarkusTest
public class DataSyncConfigurationMappingMapperTest {
    @Inject
    DataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper dataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper;
        @Test
    public void testEntityToPojo() {
        DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity entity = new DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity();
        entity.setColumnNames("column1,column2,column3");
        entity.setOldValue("name");
        DataSyncConfigurationEntity dataSyncConfigurationEntity = new DataSyncConfigurationEntity();
        dataSyncConfigurationEntity.setName("sss");
        dataSyncConfigurationEntity.setColumnNames("a1,b2,c3");
        entity.setDataSyncConfiguration(dataSyncConfigurationEntity);
        DataSyncConfigurationMapping pojo = dataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper.entityToPojo(entity);
        assertEquals(entity.getId(), pojo.getId());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(entity.getColumnNames().split(",")), pojo.getColumnNameList());
        assertNotNull(pojo.getDataSyncConfiguration());
        assertEquals(dataSyncConfigurationEntity.getName(), pojo.getDataSyncConfiguration().getName());
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(dataSyncConfigurationEntity.getColumnNames().split(",")), pojo.getDataSyncConfiguration().getColumnNameList());
    }
}
```

Like i mention on my code i tried to use stringToListConverter and listToStringConverter named methods to convert, but couldn't accomplished for this fields.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes on your Mappers and they worked:

1- Use "spring" instead of "jakarta" as the componentModel in @Mapper

2- Use abstract class instead of interface for Mappers

3- Remove redundant Named methods in the DataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper

These are the classes I changed:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {DataSyncConfigurationMapper.class})
public abstract class DataSyncConfigurationMappingMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "columnNames", target = "columnNameList",
            qualifiedByName = "stringToListConverter")
    public abstract DataSyncConfigurationMapping entityToPojo(DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity entity);

    @Mapping(source = "columnNameList", target = "columnNames",
            qualifiedByName = "listToStringConverter")
    public abstract DataSyncConfigurationMappingEntity pojoToEntity(DataSyncConfigurationMapping pojo);

}
```

And the DataSyncConfigurationMapper

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Named;

import java.util.List;

import static com.thunder.light.model.mapstruct.MapperUtils.listToString;
import static com.thunder.light.model.mapstruct.MapperUtils.stringToList;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class  DataSyncConfigurationMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "columnNames", target = "columnNameList", qualifiedByName = "stringToListConverter")
    public abstract DataSyncConfiguration entityToPojo(DataSyncConfigurationEntity entity);

    @Mapping(source = "columnNameList", target = "columnNames", qualifiedByName = "listToStringConverter")
    public abstract DataSyncConfigurationEntity pojoToEntity(DataSyncConfiguration pojo);

    @Named("stringToListConverter")
    public List<String> map(String value){
        return stringToList(value);
    }

    @Named("listToStringConverter")
     public String map(List<String> list){
        return listToString(list);
    }
}
```